# Rotating Vectors Manually

Tags: c++, vector, rotation

I am trying to make this function read ten integer values (entered by the user at the keyboard) into a vector, then ask the user how many times it should right rotate the vector elements in a cyclical fashion. The function should then perform the given number of rotations and output the resulting rotated vector. Here is what I have so far. The problem I am experiencing is that when the program is ran, the output is incorrect. It does not correctly rotate the vectors. I am entering 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 as the input, then the number 2 as the number of rotations and the output I am getting is 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void function2()
{

    int num;
    vector<int> rotate;

    int num_rotate = 0;
    cin >> num_rotate;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cin >> num;
        rotate.push_back(num);
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < num_rotate; ++x)
    {

        int n = rotate[9];

        for (int i = 8; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            rotate[i + 1] = rotate[i];

        }
        rotate[0] = n;

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rotate.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << rotate[i] << ", ";
    }
}

int main()
{

    function2();
}
```

Comment: What is the question? If something isn't working, describe the observed behavior and explain how it differs from the expected behavior.

Comment: If the first function has no bearing at all on the question, do not include it and do not mention it. It only distracts from the real question and from the relevant parts of the code.

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `function2` looks OK to me, but I've only run it in my head. Say what input you give, what output you get and what output you expect. It's not hard to do.

Comment: In `int n = rotate[9];` 9 seems weirdly specific. `rotate.size()-1` may be a better choice. Similar problem with `for (int i = 8; i >= 0; --i)` and 8.

Comment: Your function is working fine. You do remember that the first input is the number of rotations, right? By your output it looks like you are entering it *after* the numbers, which would rotate the vector `[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,2]` 1 time

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that function first asks to enter number of rotations and then numbers to rotate. Wrong input order. Populate vector first and then set number of rotations:

```
int num;
vector<int> rotate;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cin >> num;
    rotate.push_back(num);
}

int num_rotate = 0;
cin >> num_rotate;
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't realize this. Thank you!